# Laravel set slug attribute

Tags: php, laravel, attributes, slug

am trying to automatically set first name and last name to slug on store and update. but am getting error: General error: 1364 Field 'slug' doesn't have a default value.

I have this in the model, what am doing wrong?

```
    public function setSlugAttribute($value)
    {
        $firstName = $this->attributes['first_name'];
        $lastName = $this->attributes['last_name'];

        $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($firstName . ' ' . $lastName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the field `slug` to the `$fillable` array of your model?

Try to remove the method parameter `$value` like in this example. Additionally, there is an easier way to access the attributes.

```
public function setSlugAttribute()
{
    $firstName = $this->first_name;
    $lastName = $this->last_name;

    $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($firstName . ' ' . $lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Accessor does not run automatically without going through your call.

One option would be to override the `fill()` method to assign the value for you:

```
//override on model
public function fill(array $attributes): Model
{
    $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name);
    return parent::fill($attributes);
}
```

Or `save()` method (not recomended):

```
public function save(array $options = []): bool
{
    $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name);
    return parent::save($options);
}
```

And in your controller call the instance this way:

```
$model = new $model();
$model->fill($request->all());
$model->save();
```